# Class Cast Exception when querying SOLR

Tags: java, exception, solr, solrj

I am getting the following Exception when trying to query my SOLR 7.5.0 standalone collection.  I am not sure where the problem is or how to go about debugging it.  I'm currently using the solr 7.5.0 dependencies in my maven project and I've tried using 7.6.0 and 7.4.0 and they produce the same Exception.  I'm looking for other things to try and figure out where the problem is and how to work around it.

The line that causes the exception is this

`QueryResponse resp = httpSolrClient.query(query, METHOD.GET );`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocumentList
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse.setResponse(QueryResponse.java:126)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:194)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.query(SolrClient.java:974)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.query(SolrClient.java:990)
    at com.leidos.textanalysis.solr.QuerySolr.main(QuerySolr.java:28)
```

Below is the code that causes it and no amount of tinkering with it has yielded any change of results.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    NoOpResponseParser responseParser = new NoOpResponseParser();
    responseParser.setWriterType("xml");

    HttpSolrClient.Builder builder = new HttpSolrClient.Builder();
    builder.withBaseSolrUrl("http://host:8983/solr/collection");

    RequestWriter writer = new RequestWriter();
    HttpSolrClient httpSolrClient = builder. build();
    httpSolrClient.setRequestWriter(writer);
    httpSolrClient.setParser(responseParser); 
    //message score
    SolrQuery query =new SolrQuery("*:*"); 

    QueryResponse resp = httpSolrClient.query(query, METHOD.GET ); //Exception thrown here

    SolrDocumentList theList =  resp.getResults();
    SolrDocument test = theList.get(0);
    System.out.println(test.toString());
}
```

Looking at the source code of QueryResponse in solr, we can see the problem is here where it casts to `SolrDocumentList`.  I cannot find a way to work around this or fix it.  I'm looking for things to try and options to troubleshoot more.  Thanks.

```
public void setResponse( NamedList<Object> res )  {
super.setResponse( res );

// Look for known things
for( int i=0; i<res.size(); i++ ) {
  String n = res.getName( i );
  if( "responseHeader".equals( n ) ) {
    _header = (NamedList<Object>) res.getVal( i );
  }
  else if( "response".equals( n ) ) {
    _results = (SolrDocumentList) res.getVal( i ); //Exception thrown Here 
  }
  else if( "sort_values".equals( n ) ) {
    _sortvalues = (NamedList<ArrayList>) res.getVal( i );
  }
  else if( "facet_counts".equals( n ) ) {
    _facetInfo = (NamedList<Object>) res.getVal( i );
    // extractFacetInfo inspects _results, so defer calling it
    // in case it hasn't been populated yet.
  }
  else if( "debug".equals( n ) ) {
    _debugInfo = (NamedList<Object>) res.getVal( i );
    extractDebugInfo( _debugInfo );
  }
  else if( "grouped".equals( n ) ) {
    _groupedInfo = (NamedList<Object>) res.getVal( i );
    extractGroupedInfo( _groupedInfo );
  }
  else if("expanded".equals(n)) {
    NamedList map = (NamedList) res.getVal(i);
    _expandedResults = map.asMap(1);
  }
  else if( "highlighting".equals( n ) ) {
    _highlightingInfo = (NamedList<Object>) res.getVal( i );
    extractHighlightingInfo( _highlightingInfo );
  }
  else if ( "spellcheck".equals( n ) )  {
    _spellInfo = (NamedList<Object>) res.getVal( i );
    extractSpellCheckInfo( _spellInfo );
  }
  else if ("clusters".equals(n)) {
    _clusterInfo = (ArrayList<NamedList<Object>>) res.getVal(i);
    extractClusteringInfo(_clusterInfo);
  }
  else if ( "suggest".equals( n ) )  {
    _suggestInfo = (Map<String,NamedList<Object>>) res.getVal( i );
    extractSuggesterInfo(_suggestInfo);
  }
  else if ( "stats".equals( n ) )  {
    _statsInfo = (NamedList<Object>) res.getVal( i );
    extractStatsInfo( _statsInfo );
  }
  else if ( "terms".equals( n ) ) {
    _termsInfo = (NamedList<NamedList<Object>>) res.getVal( i );
    extractTermsInfo( _termsInfo );
  }
  else if ( "moreLikeThis".equals( n ) ) {
    _moreLikeThisInfo = (NamedList<SolrDocumentList>) res.getVal( i );
  }
  else if ( CursorMarkParams.CURSOR_MARK_NEXT.equals( n ) ) {
    _cursorMarkNext = (String) res.getVal( i );
  }
}
if(_facetInfo != null) extractFacetInfo( _facetInfo );
```

}

Comment: Why are you using the `NoOpResponseParser`?

Comment: @MatsLindh good question.  It was code I copied from somewhere.  When I switched to binaryResponseParser, it started to work.

Answer (score 1):

Credit goes to MatsLindh for pointing me in the right direction.  `NoOpResponseParser` puts the response in a `NamedList` object and doesn't actually return a `Response` object.  See [this for more information on the `NoOpResponseParser`](https://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/01/08/using-solr-cloud-for-robustness-but-returning-json-format/).
There are a few Parser options here to use instead. They all extend [`ResponseParser`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/7_5_0//solr-solrj/index.html?org/apache/solr/client/solrj/ResponseParser.html).

`BinaryResponseParser, DelegationTokenResponse.JsonMapResponseParser, InputStreamResponseParser, NoOpResponseParser, XMLResponseParser`